# FMS based video chat - Best practices

Tags: flash, apache-flex, flash-media-server

I am working on a video-chat application, with FMS  4.

While it's really easy to make one, thanks to Adobe, I found it hard to make it a good one.

I'm looking for any advice on the server configuration (machine configuration  server.xml, applicatio.xml and so on) or on client implementation (bandwidth handling, cam and mic settings...).

Any insight is greatly appreciated 
Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by a "good one"?

Comment: A one with good audio/video quality, as low latency as possible, maximum server performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My questoion was dircectly answered here:
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashmediaserver/articles/real-time-collaboration.html

and here:
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/rtmfp_cirrus_app.html

Thanks.